# PyQt, how to check if array of numbers is of specific length

Tags: postgresql, pyqt

I'm linking my PyQt code with my PostgreSQL, and inside PostgreSQL I've put that certain columns are NUMERIC(11,0) type, but now I'd like to limit it to exactly 11 digits, since NUMERIC(11,0)  means maximum of 11 digits.

```
class kirurg_GUI(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_kirurg_Widget):
       def __init__(self):
              QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
              self.setupUi(self)
              self.kirurg_Add_button.clicked.connect(self.insert_kirurg)

       def insert_kirurg(self):
              oib_kir = self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.text()
              if not oib_kir:
                     QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Query error', 'oib_kir must not be empty')

              else: 
                     query = QSqlQuery()
                     status = query.exec("INSERT INTO kirurg (oib_kir, prezime, ime, adresa, broj_telefona)"
                                         "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (''.join(self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                                    ''.join(self.kirurg_prezime_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                                    ''.join(self.kirurg_ime_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                                    ''.join(self.kirurg_adresa_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                                    ''.join(self.kirurg_broj_telefona_lineEdit.text())))
                     if status is not True:
                            errorText = query.lastError().text()
                            QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Query error', errorText)

                     else:
                            msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
                            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Kirurg")
                            msgBox.setText("Data entered successfully")
                            msgBox.exec_()
                            kirurg.close()
```

Here is part of my code where I'm adding values inside my DB.

This line:

```
''.join(self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.text()
```

should be exactly 11 digits long. I got it covered for maximum size, and numeric type but now I'd like to limit it to exact number of digits.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can use [`QLineEdit.setInputMask (self, QString inputMask)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setInputMask) ot set number only. Read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) to config them.

```
class kirurg_GUI (QtGui.QWidget, Ui_kirurg_Widget):
    def __init__ (self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.kirurg_Add_button.clicked.connect(self.insert_kirurg)
        maxLength = 11                                                      # <- Add length
        self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.setInputMask(('9' * maxLength) + ';_') # <- Set input mask
        self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.setMaxLength(maxLength)                # <- Set max length

    def insert_kirurg (self):
        oib_kir = self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.text()
        if not oib_kir:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Query error', 'oib_kir must not be empty')
        if len(str(oib_kir)) != self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.maxLength():                   # Check digit length
            QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Query error', 'oib_kir must not be 11 diget') # Not 11 digit ? Error!
        else:
            query = QSqlQuery()
            status = query.exec("INSERT INTO kirurg (oib_kir, prezime, ime, adresa, broj_telefona)"
                                "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (''.join(self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                           ''.join(self.kirurg_prezime_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                           ''.join(self.kirurg_ime_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                           ''.join(self.kirurg_adresa_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                           ''.join(self.kirurg_broj_telefona_lineEdit.text())))
            if status is not True:
                errorText = query.lastError().text()
                QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Query error', errorText)
            else:
                msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
                msgBox.setWindowTitle("Kirurg")
                msgBox.setText("Data entered successfully")
                msgBox.exec_()
                kirurg.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't use maxLength property ?

```
self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.setMaxLength(11);
```

Or you can try to add a event filter like this. Maybe I am wrong

```
class Filter(QtCore.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
            getTxt = widget.text()
            if len(getTxt) < 11 or len(getTxt) > 11:
                 reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Critical", 
                    'Value must be 11 numbers', QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
            return False
        else:
            return False

class LimitTest(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, total=20):
        super(LimitTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self._filter = Filter()
        self.newLimitTextEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.normal = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        main_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.newLimitTextEdit, 0, 0)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.normal, 0, 1)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self._active = False
        self.newLimitTextEdit.installEventFilter(self._filter)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
bar = LimitTest(total=101)
bar.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just limit it's max lenghth? I already have that working. I need it to be exactly 11, not 9, not 10, but 11.

Comment: Updated with a event filter maybe that will help you.